# Google Earth Engine code for calculating NDWI from Sentinel 2 image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to calculate NDWI from Sentinel 2 dataset from Landsat 8 Here's my code for Landsat 8

```js
// Load an image.
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate('2017-09-01','2018-09-10');
// Define the visualization parameters.
var vizParams = {bands: ['B6', 'B5', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.5,gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]};
// Center the map and display the image.
Map.addLayer(image, vizParams, 'Band652');
// Load an image.
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate('2017-09-01','2018-09-10');
// Create an NDWI image, define visualization parameters and display.
var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']);
var ndwiViz = {min: 0.5, max: 1, palette: ['44c9f1', '1637f1']};
Map.addLayer(ndwi, ndwiViz, 'NDWI', false);

// Mask the non-watery parts of the image, where NDWI < 0.10.
var ndwiMasked = ndwi.updateMask(ndwi.gte(0.10));
Map.addLayer(ndwiMasked, ndwiViz, 'NDWI masked');
```

When I add Sentinel 2 imagecollection then I get an error like this

> image.normalizedDifference is not a function

Comment: It runs fine (https://code.earthengine.google.com/f0a27c3a98151d67048657c86c144c01). I guess you tried to rip off the problematic part of a longer code, but this is not representative of the issue

Comment: You say `sentinel 2` but in the code you use `landsat 8`, you should post the code that throws the error

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe code edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `normalizedDifference` function can be applied to single images. You are trying to apply it to a collection of images.

You can either map over that collection and calculate the NDWI for each image or reduce the collection to a single image.

The latter can be done by calculating the mean over time and then calculating the NDWI:

```js
var ndwi = image.mean().normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Load an image.
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate('2017-09-01','2018-09-10');
// Define the visualization parameters.
var vizParams = {bands: ['B6', 'B5', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.5,gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]};
// Center the map and display the image.
Map.addLayer(image, vizParams, 'Band652');
// Load an image.
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate('2017-09-01','2018-09-10');
// Create an NDWI image, define visualization parameters and display.
var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']);
var ndwiViz = {min: 0.5, max: 1, palette: ['44c9f1', '1637f1']};
Map.addLayer(ndwi, ndwiViz, 'NDWI', false);

// Mask the non-watery parts of the image, where NDWI < 0.10.
var ndwiMasked = ndwi.updateMask(ndwi.gte(0.10));
Map.addLayer(ndwiMasked, ndwiViz, 'NDWI masked');
```